# Clamscan viruses scanning, too many viruses

Tags: 22.04, security, malware, clamav

I installed ClamAV to check for some malware. It took much time, 4 hours, to scan my PC, and the results are in this screenshot:

[image]

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and tried to stay safe, but I wanted to double-check my PC integrity. Moreover, as you can see I run it again to check the logs as well.

My questions are:

1. How good is it, if anyone tried it before?
2. There are too many viruses, and I think the application categorised some other apps or files on my PC as viruses, not malware.
3. Do you have a better alternative or another solution to check my PC's integrity?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: ClamAV is a signature-based tool for detecting Windows viruses, and will give false positives on Linux, which isn't vulnerable to Windows viruses. Unless you're running a mail server with Windows clients, ClamAV on Linux is a waste of effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How good is it, if anyone tried it before?

It's at most as good as any other antivirus. Which means it doesn't protect against zero-day or targeted attacks, and can only clean up known threats a few hours after.

#### There are too many viruses, and I think the application categorised some other apps or files on my PC as viruses, not malware.

Zero is not too many.

Pay attention to the following line:

> `Infected files: 0`

You do not have any viruses on your computer. The `Known viruses: 8684188` part is good. It is saying that ClamAV knows about 8684188 malware signatures that it is protecting you from.

#### Do you have a better alternative or another solution to check my PC's integrity?

There's no competition in antivirus solution alternatives on Linux.

The best way to maintain PC integrity is to not do anything that risks the integrity. Do everything in a web browser and keep the browser and OS updated. Don't download any untrusted files.

Comment: Thank you, so much! I did not saw the "Infected files" I saw only the "Known viruses" and after viruses I saw the number. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

From the `clamscan` manpage - `man clamscan`:

```
--max-filesize=#n
    Extract  and  scan  at most #n bytes from each archive. 
    You may pass the value in kilobytes in format xK or xk, 
    or megabytes in format xM or xm, where x is a number. 
    This option protects your system against DoS attacks (default: 25 MB, max: <4 GB)
```

So use the `--max-filesize=4095M` to increase the size.

`clamav -i -r --max-filesize=4095M ~/`

Also, you don't need `sudo`. Also, you probably don't even need to scan for viruses. I've used Ubuntu for nearly 20 years, and never used an anti-virus scanner.

Answer (score 0):

heres the command you can use.

```
/usr/bin/clamscan  --block-encrypted --database=/home/user1/.clamtk/db  --scan-archive=yes --max-scansize=500M --exclude-dir=smb4k --exclude-dir=/run/user/user1/gvfs --exclude-dir=/home/user1/.gvfs --exclude-dir=^/home/user1/.clamtk/viruses --exclude-dir=^/sys/ --exclude-dir=^/dev/ --exclude-dir=^/proc/ --exclude-dir=^/wyze/ --detect-broken --recursive=yes /
```

also use

```
sudo freshclam
```

before